# Why codeigniter session expires frequently ? also user is active on site

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I'm using codeigniter for my app. development.

These are the session settings. I'm using DB session.

```
$config['sess_cookie_name']= 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration']= 7200;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']= 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']= FALSE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;
```

I am not using AJAX or dynamic resources loading the session library.
Also I have checked session data,all data are saving in DB.

This is working well on localhost.

Comment: That cookie name is technically not valid - most browsers accept it anyway, but if you are using Internet Explorer 9 it will refuse to register a session with an underscore in the name and instead of telling you, it will just silently fail.

Comment: I am using only now crome , mozilla now ?

Answer (score 0):

By default it's expire every 2 hours (7200) but check if in your app destroy session in some cases.
If you want to increase the hours wirte a bigger number than 7200 in $config['sess_expiration'].
Example:

```
$config['sess_expiration']= 18000; //5 hours
```

If you want that the session doesn't expire write:

```
$config['sess_expiration']= 0;
```

Comment: I have set like `$config['sess_expiration']= 7200;` but before 7200 seconds ,session is expiring frequently. why? i have also checked setting like- `$config['sess_expiration']= 0;`

Comment: Look at this link: http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/153084/#741225 @ChandanSroniyan

Comment: this like is not usable for me...give another solution.