# Expire session automatically in Codeigniter Native session

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, session-cookies

I need to keep a session alive for 30 minutes and then destroy it there is no action/activity within 30 minutes. I am using codeigniter native session. I added expiration time in config file such as:

```
   $config['sess_expiration'] = 1800;
```

But this is not working. Anyone know how to set session expire time in codeigniter Native session library?

Comment: try this link..i think this question is already asked  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15571824/why-codeigniter-session-expires-frequently-also-user-is-active-on-site?rq=1

Comment: @RavindraShekhawat,I am not using codeigniter default session library,I am using native session

Comment: have you checked my answer??

Comment: @RavindraShekhawat,yes,But in my library sess_time_to_update not exist

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that codeigniter's sessions aren't actual php sessions but rather their own way of handing user "sessions." Are you using the database to store them? If you are using them, I would highly recommend using a database, otherwise you cannot validate them.

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/sessions.html has additional information.

[How does CodeIgniter know a cookie holds valid session data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177742/how-does-codeigniter-know-a-cookie-holds-valid-session-data) may also be a good read.

Comment: ,I am not using database session

Answer (score 0):

You have set set the

> sess_expiration

and you still need to update  So i think you have to include 1 more line

> sess_time_to_update

```
$config['sess_expiration']        = 1800;
$config['sess_time_to_update']    = $config['sess_expiration'];
```